# checkbox related issue in php and html

Tags: php

I want to print the check box values(only the selected value) but the following error are shown
Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 403

localhost
Apache/2.4.7 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1e PHP/5.5.9
here is the entire php file ... i am new in php ... so plz check my code..there may b some error ...

```
<?php // File: anyco.php
    require('anyco_ui.inc.php');
    // Create a database connection
    $conn = oci_connect('system','123','localhost/orcl');
    ui_print_header('FoodItemList');

    //session_start();
    //$cid=$_SESSION['cid'];
                   do_query($conn, 'SELECT Fooditem_ID,Food_item_name,price,day_available,time_available,discount_percentage,start_date,deadline FROM Food_Item');
                   ui_print_footer(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    // Execute query and display results
    function do_query($conn, $query)
    {
            $stid = oci_parse($conn, $query);
            $r = oci_execute($stid,OCI_DEFAULT);
            print '<table border="1">';
            print '<tr>';
            print '<td>Food_ID<td>Food_Name<td>Price(tk)<td>Dvailable_day<td>Avaliable_time<td>Discount<td>Dis_start date<td>Dis_finish date<td>selected item<td>quanity';
            while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) 
            {
                print '<tr>';
                $num=1;
                $val="";
                foreach ($row as $item) 
                {                  
                    if($num==1)
                    { 
                       $val = $item;
                       $num=2;
                    }

                    print '<td>'.($item!== null ? htmlentities($item) : '&nbsp;').'</td>';

                }

                echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="ticked[]" value="$val"></td>';
                echo '<td><input type="number" name ="name[]" ></td>';
                print '</tr>';
           }

       print '</table>';
    } 

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])&&)
    {
              echo'yeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee';
             $ticked = $_POST['ticked'];
             foreach ($ticked as $ticked=>$value) 
             {
                 echo "values selected are : ".$value."<br />";
             }
    }

?>
<html>
<style>
body
{
background:orange;
}
</style>
<body text="green">
<br><br>
<form action="<?php echo $current_file;?>" method="POST">


    <input type ="submit" value="Submit"><br><br>   
</form>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is remove `&&`

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])&&)
                          ^ remove the &&
```

---

then change this

```
<input type ="submit" value="Submit"><br><br>
```

to

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"><br><br>
```

because `isset($_POST['submit'])` is looking for a `name=""`

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    echo'yeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee';

    // more of your code...
}
?>
```

---

**Edit**

remove

```
action="<?php echo $current_file;?>"
```

from

```
<form action="<?php echo $current_file;?>" method="POST">
```

so it should be just

```
<form method="POST">
```

Comment: @user3460746 the 403 means that you can't read the file.. change your permissions...

Comment: only when i click submit the following error is shown

Comment: @user3460746 remove `action="<?php echo $current_file;?>"`... it must be redirecting you to the wrong place... if you are submitting to the same file, you can just omit it.

Comment: when i omit it is is showing Notice: Undefined index: ticked in E:\Xamp\htdocs\FoodItemList.php on line 47

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in E:\Xamp\htdocs\FoodItemList.php on line 48

Comment: That is because `<input type="checkbox" name="ticked[]" value="$val">` is outside of your `<form> </form>`... the only values that are submitted are what is inside the `<form>` tags

Comment: plz tell me what to do ...if i want this value